# swift 3 asking permission while using camera

Tags: ios, swift3, permissions, camera, plist

I have read many of articles regarding on this issues that only adds lines of code on plist like:

```
Key     :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```

but i still got the same issue that

ERROR MESSAGE

> 'Attempted to start scanning on a device with no camera. Check requestCameraPermissionWithSuccess: method before calling
>   startScanningWithResultBlock:'

It seems like it still do not have the permission on using the camera on the apps

but then actually how are we going to gain camera access on iOS device?

and this are my code

```
    MTBBarcodeScanner.requestCameraPermission(success: { success in
        if success {
            do {
                try self.scanner?.startScanning(resultBlock: { codes in
                    if let codes = codes {
                        for code in codes {
                            let stringValue = code.stringValue!
                            print("Found code: \(stringValue)")

                            if (stringValue != nil)
                            { ... }

                                    })
                                }))
                                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            } catch {
                NSLog("Unable to start scanning")
            }
        } else {
            UIAlertView(title: "Scanning Unavailable", message: "This app does not have permission to access the camera", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Ok").show()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Is anywhere else the function `startScanning ` is called?

Comment: ya the function is called inside the pod file.

Comment: That calling is not in `requestCameraPermission` block?

Comment: ya its somewhere inside this code

(BOOL)startScanningWithResultBlock:(void (^)(NSArray<AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *> *codes))
NSAssert([MTBBarcodeScanner cameraIsPresent], @"Attempted to start scanning on a device with no camera. Check requestCameraPermissionWithSuccess: method before calling startScanningWithResultBlock:");

Comment: Sounds your device does not have a camera, did you run the app on a Simulator?

Comment: ya i tried it on simulator it gives me that error

by the way i tried it on older iPad everything works fine...but when i tried it on iOS10 iPad it shows me that i dont have the permission to access the camera

Answer (score 0):

in order to get access to the devices' camera you have to provide a Camera Usage Description.
You do this in your Info.plist file.

Simply click the "+" icon next to where it says "Information Property List" and type `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`.
Then as a value provide a short usage info, for example "We need access in order to scan barcodes."

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya i tried it but when i reinstall the app on my iPad it din prompt me any permission message on enabling camera usage